# Get context of current route

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I've implemented a search field in my ember app using ember router. The relevant portion of my router looks like this:

```
question: Em.Route.extend({
  route: '/?query=:query'
  connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
    query = context['query'],
    articles = App.get('defaultStore').findQuery(App.Article, {"query": query})
    router.get('helpController').connectOutlet('articlesSearch', 'articlesSearch', articles)
  }
})
```

I want to bind the value of my search field to the current route's context. I found a way to do this in my controller using the `stateMetaFor` method which is implemented in my controller like this:

```
query: function() {
  router = App.get('router')
  state = router.findStateByPath(router.get('currentState'), 'help.question')

  if (router.get('currentState') == state) {
    stateMeta = router.stateMetaFor(state)
    return stateMeta['context']['query]
  }

  return ''
}.property('App.router.currentState').cacheable()
```

I'm not content with this method because 1) it uses the undocumented `findStateByPath` method and 2) because it requires knowledge of internals of the stateMeta object. Is there a better way to do this? If there isn't, should there be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to display information in your views is to make it available on a controller, and have your views bind to that.

In this instance, the idiomatic thing to do would be to set a `query` property on the `helpController`:

```
router.set('helpController.query', query);
```